# Hardhat.config.js: Cannot find module '@ethersproject/experimental/nonce-manager'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ethereum, hardhat

I'm having trouble including the `NonceManager` class in my hardhat config:

I can't use `import` statements in the file it seems. So I've tried

`const NonceManager = require("@ethersproject/experimental/nonce-manager");`

and

`const { NonceManager } = require("@ethersproject/experimental/nonce-manager");`

But I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module '@ethersproject/experimental/nonce-manager'

My `devDependencies` in `package.json` include:

`"@ethersproject/experimental": "^5.6.0",` and `"ethers": "^5.6.0",`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. For context, here is the file and its exports: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/experimental/lib/nonce-manager.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to `npm install`?

When you clone an existing project, the `node_modules` folder is often in the `.gitignore` to save space and download time. This means that you should `cd` to your project folder and run `npm install`, which will download any missing packages.

EDIT: It appears you're just using the wrong import/require. Here is the correct way to import it:

```js
// Node
const { NonceManager } = require("@ethersproject/experimental");

// ESM/TypeScript
import { NonceManager } from "@ethersproject/experimental";
```

See the bottom of https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/experimental/

Comment: If this fixed your issue, please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers 'ethers@^5.0.0'
```

As such, it will download the missing library to run the script.